# What does にと do?

Tags: particles

I have a sentence that I'm having some trouble with. It's from a game called Tales of Graces -- basically, at one point you go to a garden and grab one of these rare flowers from there. The sentence is the description that is displayed when you view the flower in your inventory.

> 裏山の花畑へ行った証拠にと、摘んだ花。

Something like "A flower that proves you went to the garden out on the hill", right? I get the gist of the sentence, but I'm not clear on what function にと has after 証拠. Is it a combination of the particles に and と? Does this combination carry any significant nuance?

Comment: If it is a game I don't know it but I see you also have what looks like a good answer, showing the ellipsis that often happens. (I also see the sentence can be found at kumicyou.sakura.ne.jp/tog/item_type_6_1.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Answer

It's translated like:

```
A flower I took to use it as an evidence that I went to the flower garden on the hill (at the back of something like a house).
```

## Reference

If a person uses `(One's thinking) と、N`, s/he wants to use N along his/her thinking.

Like:

```
彼へのお[土産]{みやげ}にと、[買]{か}ってきたお[菓子]{かし}。 -> A candy I bought to make it a souvenir for him.
縄跳びで[遊]{あそ}ぼうと、[持]{も}ってきた[縄]{なわ}。 -> A rope I took to play rope-skipping.
```

Please take a look at `に`.

The point is that some verbs are hid after `に`. Let's add `しよう`, `[思]{おも}って`, and `「」` to make it easier to understand.

```
彼へのお[土産]{みやげ}にと、[買]{か}ってきたお[菓子]{かし}。 = 「彼へのお[土産]{みやげ}にしよう」と思って、[買]{か}ってきたお[菓子]{かし}。
縄跳びで[遊]{あそ}ぼうと、[持]{も}ってきた[縄]{なわ}。 = 「縄跳びで[遊]{あそ}ぼう」と思って、[持]{も}ってきた[縄]{なわ}。
[裏山]{うらやま}の[花畑]{はなばたけ}へ[行]{い}った[証拠]{しょうこ}にと、[摘]{つ}んだ[花]{はな}。 = 「[裏山]{うらやま}の[花畑]{はなばたけ}へ[行]{い}った[証拠]{しょうこ}にしよう」と思って、[摘]{つ}んだ[花]{はな}。
```

You can see that the hero (or else?) thought that he wanted to use `摘んだ花` as `裏山の花畑へ行った証拠`.

Comment: Would you say this usage is mainly for used from a narrative perspective?

Comment: @hulapoll1 In my personal opinion, yes.