# What is the function of the に in 仕上げに?

Tags: particle-に

「......てめえ、覚えてろよ」

「女の子はそんな言葉遣いしちゃ駄目よ。そうそう、**仕上げに**これをつけてちょうだい」

「あ？」

士道は眉をひそめながら、琴里から絆創膏のようなものを受け取った。

「それをのどに貼り付けてみて」

Context: the first speaker is the brother (士道) and the second speaker the sister (琴里). The sister forced her brother to dress as a girl. And she gave him a device for him to stick to his throat, so that the brother’s voice could change into a girl’s voice.

Hi. What is the function of the に in 仕上げに? Is the に the same as として? Or does the に indicate purpose?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This に is a role/function marker ("as" or "for" in English). 仕上げにこれをつける means "to put/use this as a finishing touch". 仕上げに is indeed interchangeable with 仕上げとして (although I feel the latter is a bit verbose in a casual sentence like this).

Similar examples can be found here:

- [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- [I really can't understand the use of に + と USED TOGETHER in this clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76801/5010)
- [Meaning of にと思って in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010)