# Using に to indicate purpose without a movement verb

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I found the following sentence in the iknow core 1000 step 9:

[image]

> 夕食に牛肉を買った。
> I bought beef for dinner.

に is marking the purpose of buying beef?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76801/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010

Comment: One of the particles to express aim, https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-aims

Answer (score 0):

に is for *for* in that sentence. So yes, it's marking purposes of buying beef.